# How to create a clone of a 2d array?

Tags: java, function, methods, boolean

I am trying to create a clone of myBoard[][] because right now when I try to return it I get all false values which can't be right.

Where exactly would I clone it, and how, so that I would get a copy of a myBoard[][] with legitimate values instead of all false? I am trying to return it at the bottom with public boolean[][] getBoard()

```
package model;

public class NQueensModel
{
    private int myNumsQueen;
    public int myPossibilities=0;
    private boolean[][] myBoard;
    private boolean[][] myGridBoard;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //...
    }
    public NQueensModel(int nQueens)
    {
        myNumsQueen = nQueens;
        myPossibilities=0;
        myBoard = new boolean[myNumsQueen][myNumsQueen];
    }
    public boolean solvePuzzle()
    {
        return solvePuzzle(0);            
    }
    private boolean solvePuzzle(int ncolumn)
    {
        if(ncolumn>myNumsQueen-1)
        {               
            myPossibilities++;
        }
        int i;       
        for( i =0; i<myNumsQueen;i++)
        {           
            if(this.isSafeMove(i, ncolumn)==true)
            {                
                this.placeQueen(i,ncolumn);
                if(this.solvePuzzle(ncolumn+1)==true)
                {                           
                    return true;                          
                }
                this.removeQueen(i, ncolumn);
            }                     
        }                  
        return false;            
    }

    private boolean doIt(int county)
    {
        if(county>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isSafeMove(int row, int col)
    {
        if(row <0 || row>=myNumsQueen || col<0 || col>=myNumsQueen)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(this.checkLowerDiag(row, col)==true ||this.checkUpperDiag(row, col)==true ||this.checkLeft(row,col)==true)
         {
             return false;
         }
         else
         {              
            return true;
         }             
    }

    private boolean checkUpperDiag(int row, int col)
    {    
        if(row==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=row, j = col; i>=0 && j>=0; i--, j--)
            {
                if(myBoard[i][j]==true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkLowerDiag(int row, int col)
    {            
        if(col==0 )
        {           
            return false;             
        }
        if(row==myNumsQueen-1){
            return false;
        }
        else
        {                
            for(int i = row, j = col; i<myNumsQueen && j>=0;  i++, j--)
            {   
                if(j>=myNumsQueen)
                {
                    return false;
                }                   
                else if(myBoard[i][j]==true)
                {
                    return true;                        
                }                                       
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkLeft(int row, int col)
    {
        if(col==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            for(int i = col; i>=0; i--)
            {                   
                if(i>=myNumsQueen)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                else if(myBoard[row][i]==true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }          
    }
    private boolean placeQueen(int row, int col)
    {
        if(col>=myNumsQueen)
        {
            return false;
        }

        myBoard[row][col] = true;
        return true;
    }
    private boolean removeQueen(int row, int col)
    {
        myBoard[row][col] = false;
        return false;
    }
    public int getPossibilities(){
        return myPossibilities;
    }
    public boolean[][] getBoard()
    {
        for(int i  = 0; i<5; i++)
        {               
            for(int j = 0; j<5; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("myBoard : " +myBoard[i][j]);
            }
        }           
        return myBoard;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is all false and you suspect it shouldn't be, cloning is not the solution (it will just create a new board of false values), something else is wrong.

Comment: It's giving me the correct amount of possibilities for everything which means that it is working the way it is supposed to, I just need one instance of the possibility

Comment: Why is the content of the `main(..)` edited out?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: They are just system.out.printing things that i was checking before

Comment: @arynaq why copying it "manually" is better than cloning ? it should have the same result

Comment: If the problem is not the "cloning" - change the title of the question. Further, please post only the relevant code - nobody wants to go through all your code.

Comment: @alfasin The problem (as it appears to me, still not clear enough..) is that he is trying to access the board with getBoard() but the returned board is "all false", why a clone would fix this is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're just looking to create a cloned array, you would have to build it by iterating over the old array and copying the values over:

```
for (int i = 0; i < oldArray.length; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < oldArray[0].length; ++j)
    newArray[i][j] = oldArray[i][j];
```

Comment: thats giving me invocation target exception

Comment: @user2909132 if our solutions (which both of them work!) don't work for you - you should either debug or at least check out the stacktrace and see where is the root of the issue. It doesn't mean that these answers are no good - it just means that you were looking in the wrong place!

Comment: i and j precrement should be an increment, otherwise all zeros will be skipped.

Comment: @LeeAllan ?? The index variable does not get incremented until after the loop executes.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using native types you can use `clone()`.

```
public static boolean[][] clone2DArray(boolean [][] array){
     // this clone is a shallow copy
     boolean[][] newArray =(boolean[][]) array.clone();
    //now you need to clone each array cause still referring to the same
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        newArray[i]=Arrays.copyOf(array[i],array[i].length); 
        //newArray[i]=(boolean[])array[i].clone(); this is valid too           
    }
       return newArray;
}
```

Read more in [Arrays#copyOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28boolean%5B%5D,%20int%29)

Comment: @alfasin Your `clone` is not deep, each array will be the same you still have to clone the "subarrays" too!

Comment: @alfasin is a 2d array

Comment: @alfasin Don't work i just try it..here is the code `public static void main(String args[]) {
     boolean [][] array = new boolean[3][3];
     
     
     System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
     
     System.out.println("clone array: ");
     boolean [] [] cloned = array.clone();
     array[0][0] = true;
     System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(cloned));
     
     
    }`